# How to make random nextInt work in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

So I try using "nextInt" but it just counts as an Error and my app won't start please help!

```
val randomValues = List(1) { Random.nextInt(0, 10) }
```

I tried Importing "nextInt" but it does nothing, it just marks it as an error.

Comment: **What error**, exactly?

Comment: Did you import the wrong Random by any chance? You need to import the Kotlin one.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly I have to import?

Comment: Like, imported this one "import kotlin.random.Random.Default.nextInt"

Comment: `import kotlin.randomRandom` instead of `java.util.Random`. The `java.util.Random` requires you to instantiate first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin has its own version of the `Random` utility class:

```
import kotlin.random.Random

class Main {
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val randomValues = List(1) { Random.nextInt(0, 10) }
    }
}
```